# structure of sentence with an economics content

Tags: expression-choice

I want to reword the following:

"The ability of trade balance to withstand the acceleration of wages depends negatively on the level of employment. "

Thank you so much FumbleFingers and Weather Vane for helping me narrow down my options. I really appreciate your help! So we have 2 options:

1. The response of the balance of trade to the acceleration of wages varies inversely with the level of employment.
2. The extent to which the trade balance is affected by wage acceleration depends inversely on the employment level.

Which is more appropriate?

Comment: I can't say that a trade balance has ability – it is a fact. Did you mean 'inversely' for 'negatively'?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Yes, negatively stands for inversely. As for the word 'ability': I agree with you. How can I then say? I mean, usually, the acceleration of wages produces a deficit in the balance of trade. However, if the level of employment is low(er), the acceleration of wage is 'slow(er)'. This is why I wrote the original sentence, i.e. "The ability of trade balance to withstand the acceleration of wages depends negatively on the level of employment. "

Comment: What @WeatherVane said. Regardless of whether a trade balance can have the "ability to withstand" rapid wage growth, it would probably be something that ***varies inversely with** [the level of employment]*, rather than *depends negatively* on it.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? "The response of the balance of trade to the acceleration of wages depends negatively on the level of employment."

Comment: The extent to which a trade balance is affected by wage increases depends inversely on the employment level.